# Android How to verify successful installation of ACRA crash logging

Tags: android, logging

I followed the instructions for adding ACRA to my project as follows:

http://code.google.com/p/acra/wiki/BasicSetup

Aside from waiting for a crash, how can I verify I set up everything properly?  Is there a way to get it to log some sort of success message?  Or do I have to purposely put in an error that will cause it to crash?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just do int i = 10/0; in constructor. :D

Comment: Please keep in mind that if you don't use "i" the optimizer might ignore the assignment (no error).
I would suggest to throw an exception.

Answer (score 16):

Throw a [RuntimeException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/RuntimeException.html).

```
throw new RuntimeException("Dying on purpose");
```

Instances of `RuntimeException` (and its subclasses) are unchecked, so the compiler won't complain.

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to get a copy of the report you can do the following....
ACRA.getErrorReporter().handleSilentException(null);

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your app startup code:

```
throw new Exception("ACRA is alive!");
```

Comment: Or just divide by 0, that one never fails

Comment: Yes, I tried the divide by zero, which was my initial idea before posting this question.  When I try to throw an exception Eclipse tells me to surround it with a try/catch block!

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the best way to prove everything's set up properly is to generate an error to see if the report was indeed sent to you. ACRA is invented for sending crash logs, so you should test it on a crash. Just comment out some line of code to make your application crash, that's all. Hope this helps.

Comment: That's kinda what the other guy already said.  And the whole reason I installed it in the first place was to get crash notifications.  In any case, I haven't read up on the meta site too much but, in my opinion, I only accept answers that I agree with.  I don't accept answers just to boost my rating.  If I should do otherwise then please refer me to an authoritative link justifying such and I'll do that in the future.  It would be great if I could change my answers in the future should a better answer come along the way though.